# Write a Scala Programs to find even numbers and a number just before it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I written the code below for finding even numbers and the number just before it in a RDD object. In this I first converted that to a List and tried to use my own function to find the even numbers and the numbers just before them. The following is my code. In this I have made an empty list in which I am trying to append the numbers one by one.

```
 object EvenandOdd
 {
  def mydef(nums:Iterator[Int]):Iterator[Int]=
  {
    val mylist=nums.toList
    val len= mylist.size
    var elist=List()
    var i:Int=0
    var flag=0
    while(flag!=1)
    {
      if(mylist(i)%2==0)
      {
        elist.++=List(mylist(i))
        elist.++=List(mylist(i-1))
      }
      if(i==len-1)
      {
        flag=1
      }
      i=i+1
    }
  }
  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
    val myrdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),2)
    val myx=myrdd.mapPartitions(mydef)
    myx.collect
  }
 }
```

I am not able to execute this command in Scala shell as well as in Eclipse and not able to figure out the error as I am just a beginner to Scala.

The following are the errors I got in Scala Shell.

```
<console>:35: error: value ++= is not a member of List[Nothing]
               elist.++=List(mylist(i))
                     ^
<console>:36: error: value ++= is not a member of List[Nothing]
               elist.++=List(mylist(i-1))
                     ^
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Iterator[Int]
           while(flag!=1)
           ^
```

Comment: Please show the specific error you are getting.

Comment: @n.m.I have added the errors I received.

Comment: a) Don't use vars. b) the 3 message informs you, that the while-loop evaluates to a Unit. As last statement of your method, it violates the assertion, to return an Iterator[Int]. c) What is the desired result of your input data? d) What is sc (sc.parallelize ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks too complicated and not functional. Also, it introduce potential problems with memory: you take Iterator as param and return Iterator as output. So, knowing that Iterator itself could be lazy and has under the hood huge amount of data, materializing it inside method with `list` could cause OOM. So your task is to get as much data from initial iterator as it it enough to answer two methods for new Iterator: `hasNext` and `next`

For example (based on your implementation, which outputs duplicates in case of sequence of even numbers) it could be:

```
  def mydef(nums:Iterator[Int]): Iterator[Int] = {
    var before: Option[Int] = None

    val helperIterator = new Iterator[(Option[Int], Int)] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = nums.hasNext

      override def next(): (Option[Int], Int) = {
        val result = (before, nums.next())
        before = Some(result._2)
        result
      }
    }
    helperIterator.withFilter(_._2 % 2 == 0).flatMap{
      case (None, next) => Iterator(next)
      case (Some(prev), next) => Iterator(prev, next)
    }
  }
```

Here you have two iterators. One helper, which just prepare data, providing previous element for each next. And next on - resulting, based on helper, which filter only even for sequence elements (second in pair), and output both when required (or just one, if first element in sequence is even)

**For initial code**

Additionally to answer of @pedrorijo91, in initial code you do did not also return anything (suppose you wanted to convert `elist` to `Iterator`)

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier if you use a functional coding style rather than an iterative coding style. In functional style the basic operation is straightforward.

Given a list of numbers, the following code will find all the even numbers and the values that precede them:

```
nums.sliding(2,1).filter(_(1) % 2 == 0)
```

The sliding operation creates a list containing all possible pairs of adjacent values in the original list.
The filter operation takes only those pairs where the second value is even.
The result is an Iterator[List[Int]] where each List[Int] has two elements. You should be able to use this in your RDD framework.

Comment: Wouldn't that (`sliding`) have a performance impact? In any case, since `nums` is an Iterator, I think this "sliding operation creates a list containing all possible pairs" is not entirely correct.

Comment: @ZenMaster Hasn't JosephChacko mention something about converting an RDD to an Iterable in the question? Once this is done, performance doesn't matter anyway. However, a solution with sliding windows might actually work on a Spark Dataset.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yeah, I am more concerned with the general case, like Spark.

Answer (score 1):

It's marked part of the developer API, so there's no guarantee it'll stick around, but the [RDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions) object actually defines `sliding` for RDDs. You will have to make sure it sees elements in the order you want.

But this becomes something like

`rdd.sliding(2).filter(x => x(1) % 2 == 0)  # pairs of (preceding number, even number)`

Answer (score 0):

for the first 2 errors:

there's no `++=` operator on Lists. You will have to do `list = list ++ element`

Comment: Or even better: `list ++= element`, which will desugar to `list.++=(element)` if `list` has a `++=` member and desugar into `list = list ++ element` if it doesn't.